# automatizar llamado a metodo en un prototipo

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente proceso que funciona correctamente:

```
const Car = function (make, speed) {
  (this.make = make), (this.speed = speed);
};

Car.prototype.accelerate = function (speed) {
  this.speed += 10;
};

Car.prototype.brake = function (speed) {
  this.speed -= 5;
};

const car1 = new Car('BMW', 120);
const car2 = new Car('Mercedes', 95);

  active.textContent = '1';

accel.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const carActive = `${active.textContent}`;

  if (carActive === '1') {
    car1.accelerate(this.speed);
    speed1.textContent = car1.speed;
  } else {
    car2.accelerate(this.speed);
    speed2.textContent = car2.speed;
  }
});

brake.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const carActive = `${active.textContent}`;
  if (carActive === '1') {
    car1.brake(this.speed);
    speed1.textContent = car1.speed;
  } else {
    car2.brake(this.speed);
    speed2.textContent = car2.speed;
  }
});

toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
  active.textContent = active.textContent === '1' ? '2' : '1';
});
```

Por cierto, con dos instancias funciona, pero quiero atomatizar el llamado a los metodos con algo como esto:
armar el nombre de la instancia...
carActive = `car${active.textContent}`
y llamar el metodo
carActive.accelerate(this.speed);
pero todos los intentos con distintas formas de concatenacion me llevan al siguiente error:
Uncaught TypeError: carActive.accelerate is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.
Alguna idea? gracias.

Comment: Quieres que el código sirva para un número indefinido 'Car' ?? es eso?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Si.debe servir para un número indefinido de cars.
Pero más alla de este caso en particular, el problema es encontrar un método o función que utilize el valor de un variable como nombre de objeto para armar: objeto.metodo ...